# How to use string replace in a jquery for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to strip out the domain from the url - but not sure exactly how.  This is what I'm attempting but as you can see console.log doesnt show anything on the second try.

```
function show_records(data) {
  let html = "";
  $.each(data, function(k, v){
    console.log(v.url)  // returns full urls eg. https://google.com
    v.url = v.url.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/i, "");
    console.log(v.url)  // returns nothing
    html += `<input type="radio" name="${v.url}" /> ${ v.url }<br />`
  })
  html+='</div></div>'
  $('.editviewm').append(html);

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `var url = new URL(v.url); console.log(url.hostname);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Niet the Dark Absol Suggested, you do not need to do more codes just to achieve the hostname.

```
function show_records(data) {
  let html = "";
  $.each(data, function(k, v){
    var url = new URL(v.url); 
    console.log(url.hostname);
    html += `<input type="radio" name="${url.hostname}" /> ${ url.hostname }<br />`
  })
  html+='</div></div>'
  $('.editviewm').append(html);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your regex is matching the entire string and not just the domain name.

Use what @Niet the Dark Absol suggests in his comment

```
v.url.replace(new URL(v.url).hostname, '');
```

If you just want the path use

```
a = new URL(window.location.href);
console.log(a.pathname);
```